# Pandas dataframe search for row which exceeds threshold values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of numerical data like this:

```
Day          High         Low      
01/01/01     200          100      
02/01/01     210          100      
03/01/01     190          110
```

Per row, I dynamically generate High and Low targets based on some formula:

```
Day          High         Low      High-Target  Low-Target
01/01/01     200          100      300          70
02/01/01     210          100      315          70
03/01/01     190          110      285          77
```

And on a **per day basis**, I want to know, does the High-Target (Future High > High Target) get hit first by subsequent highs or does the Low-Target (Low Target < Future Low) get crossed first by subsequent lows? Please note, this is on a per day basis - I want to label each row with the outcome 'High Target Hit First' or 'Low Target Hit First'.

Just to make this more clear, lets label the first three days based on subsequent data.

```
Day          High         Low      High-Target  Low-Target   Hit First
01/01/01     200          100      300          70           HIGH
02/01/01     210          100      315          70           LOW
03/01/01     190          110      285          77           HIGH

04/01/01     310          120
05/01/01     310          65
06/01/01     300          120
```

So for 01/01, the target of 300 was exceeded on the day 04/01 before the target of 70 was hit the next day (05/01). Hence, the HIGH target was exceeded first.

For 02/01, the high target of 315 was not crossed but the low target of 70 was crossed on 05/01, hence the LOW target was crossed first.

For 03/01, the high target of 285 was exceeded on 04/01 before the low target of 77 was crossed on 05/01. Hence the HIGH target was crossed first.

What is the most efficient way to do this? I was thinking of using `.apply` with a search through the entire dataframe and perhaps comparing `ids` to see which target is hit first.

*To be clear - I have the entire dataframe of 3000 days. By 'subsequent data' - I just mean later days in the series.*

Comment: every subsequent row has to be checked per row; so for 01/01 - it has to check all the days until the end of the dataframe unless it finds a value that crosses either of the thresholds

Answer (score 1):

`.apply` can indeed be used here, with a custom function (that needs a reference to the whole dataframe `df`).

```
def get_hit_first(row):
    # Get a temporary view on the subsequent rows
    temp = df.loc[row.name:].iloc[1:]
    # Find the first row matching the criteria
    head = temp[(temp.High >= row['High-Target'])|(temp.Low <= row['Low-Target'])]\
        .head(1)

    if len(head) > 0:
        if head.iloc[0].High >= row['High-Target']:
            return 'HIGH'
        else:
            return 'LOW'

 df['Hit First'] = df.apply(get_hit_first, axis=1)
```

It is probably not the most optimal solution though, as the comparisons are executed on all subsequent rows.